# Protocolos para transferência de multimídia?

Tags: html5, http, vídeo

Estou desenvolvendo um site de videos, e estes ficam armazenados em um server windows, atualmente uso http://path.mp4 para buscar os arquivos de vídeo para o player HTML5, mas ai me surgiu a dúvida se HTTP é apropriado para esse tipo de uso, existe alguma restrição?

- Atualmente os vídeos levam em media de 5 a 15 segundos para começar,
  muitas requisições ao mesmo vídeo podem levar mais tempo?
- Existe algum outro protocolo que serve melhor para essa função?

Comment: Depende como vai usar. Se for usar HTTP, o mínimo que se espera é que use um servidor que suporte ranges, para a pessoa poder pular pro meio do vídeo sem carregar o começo todo antes. Tem muitas variáveis para poder dizer o que é melhor ou não pro seu caso. Essa demora pra começar pode estar relacionada justamente ao fato do sistema não estar fazendo stream, e do vídeo não estar fechado de alguma maneira que permita carga progressiva, ou outro fator do mesmo tipo obrigando o download completo antes do play. Como comentei, muitos fatores envolvidos.

Comment: São vídeos que variam de 200 a 400mb, como posso fazer para que o vídeo seja transmitido como stream? Já li que se mudar os metadados para o topo o vídeo é carregado mais rápido no player, mas não achei nada concreto

Comment: Precisa estudar sobre as formas de compactar, os tipos de container e encoding, é algo que foge um pouco do nosso escopo. Fora isso, depois precisa servir de maneira a poder fazer streaming, o que é um outro assunto que independe do fechamento do vídeo. E depende do servidor web usado também.

Comment: Vale notar que HTTP é para casos realmente de pouco uso, se for fazer algo como um servidor de vídeo mais complexo, com mais público, precisa pensar realmente em protocolos de streaming puro (que eu acredito que seja um dos elementos da sua pergunta).

Comment: Sempre que procuro sobre esses protocolos para live stream, ou vem HLS, ou RTSP, no caso sobre o que li RTSP parece funcionar bem com HTML5, vou me aprofundar mais em alguns fóruns em Inglês pois Br não tem muito sobre esse tipo de conteúdo

Comment: @Bacco usar php para fazer a stream dos arquivos seria um bom método ?

Comment: Simplesmente vai ser uma camada a mais no meio estressando o servidor.

Comment: Abri uma outra pergunta voltada mais pra essa questão do live por PHP, pra discutir melhor como funciona esse método http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/170599/vantagens-e-desvantagens-de-usar-php-v%C3%ADdeo-stream?noredirect=1#comment351640_170599