# Vantagens e desvantagens de usar PHP Vídeo Stream?

Tags: php, vídeo, stream

Pesquisando um pouco sobre a performance de videos para stream, achei uma solução que me cabe bem, que seria usar um script PHP para mandar o vídeo em partes para o player, e tal método não me forcaria a usar protocolos como RTSP ou WebSocket, mas ai fica a dúvida:

- Eu teria alguma vantagem ou desvantagem por carregar os vídeos dessa
  forma?
- Os protocolos padronizados para esse tipo de uso são mais
  recomendados?
- São explicações um pouco grandes para serem dadas em resposta por
  aqui, mas se alguém pude me indicar bons pontos, e tutoriais a
  respeito desse tipo de exibição em páginas, já seria de grande ajuda.

Atualização: Segue abaixo o código PHP para fazer a stream;
Link para o tutorial: http://codesamplez.com/programming/php-html5-video-streaming-tutorial

```
class VideoStream
{
    private $path = "";
    private $stream = "";
    private $buffer = 102400;
    private $start  = -1;
    private $end    = -1;
    private $size   = 0;

    function __construct($filePath) 
    {
        $this->path = $filePath;
    }

    /**
     * Open stream
     */
    private function open()
    {
        if (!($this->stream = fopen($this->path, 'rb'))) {
            die('Could not open stream for reading');
        }

    }

    /**
     * Set proper header to serve the video content
     */
    private function setHeader()
    {
        ob_get_clean();
        header("Content-Type: video/mp4");
        header("Cache-Control: max-age=604800, public");
        header("Expires: ".gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()+604800) . ' GMT');
        header("Last-Modified: ".gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', @filemtime($this->path)) . ' GMT' );
        $this->start = 0;
        $this->size  = filesize($this->path);
        $this->end   = $this->size - 1;
        header("Accept-Ranges: 0-".$this->end);

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {

            $c_start = $this->start;
            $c_end = $this->end;

            list(, $range) = explode('=', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], 2);
            if (strpos($range, ',') !== false) {
                header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
                header("Content-Range: bytes $this->start-$this->end/$this->size");
                exit;
            }
            if ($range == '-') {
                $c_start = $this->size - substr($range, 1);
            }else{
                $range = explode('-', $range);
                $c_start = $range[0];

                $c_end = (isset($range[1]) && is_numeric($range[1])) ? $range[1] : $c_end;
            }
            $c_end = ($c_end > $this->end) ? $this->end : $c_end;
            if ($c_start > $c_end || $c_start > $this->size - 1 || $c_end >= $this->size) {
                header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
                header("Content-Range: bytes $this->start-$this->end/$this->size");
                exit;
            }
            $this->start = $c_start;
            $this->end = $c_end;
            $length = $this->end - $this->start + 1;
            fseek($this->stream, $this->start);
            header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
            header("Content-Length: ".$length);
            header("Content-Range: bytes $this->start-$this->end/".$this->size);
        }
        else
        {
            header("Content-Length: ".$this->size);
        }  

    }

    /**
     * close curretly opened stream
     */
    private function end()
    {
        fclose($this->stream);
        exit;
    }

    /**
     * perform the streaming of calculated range
     */
    private function stream()
    {
        $i = $this->start;
        set_time_limit(0);
        while(!feof($this->stream) && $i <= $this->end) {
            $bytesToRead = $this->buffer;
            if(($i+$bytesToRead) > $this->end) {
                $bytesToRead = $this->end - $i + 1;
            }
            $data = fread($this->stream, $bytesToRead);
            echo $data;
            flush();
            $i += $bytesToRead;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Start streaming video content
     */
    function start()
    {
        $this->open();
        $this->setHeader();
        $this->stream();
        $this->end();
    }
}

/*chamo a classe*/
    $filePath = "caminho-para-o-video.mp4";
    $stream = new VideoStream($filePath);
    $stream->start();
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54286/discussion-on-question-by-leo-letto-vantagens-e-desvantagens-de-usar-php-video-s)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## HTTP Header Range (Download de arquivos por partes)

O PHP permite não só para vídeos, mas para qualquer tipo de download, montar um script de gerenciamento de entrega de partes de arquivos. É dessa maneira que site como Mega ou outros especializados em Download, gerenciam a banda utilizada, velocidade e qualquer outra limitação que o serviço tiver para usuários de conta free.

Um dos principais problemas do PHP quando utilizado para stream, websocket ou qualquer coisa do gênero é que ele é péssimo para gerenciar memória, [o PHP precisa morrer uma hora](https://software-gunslinger.tumblr.com/post/47131406821/php-is-meant-to-die). Não é nada saudavel para o servidor deixar um script do PHP rodando por séculos. Este deve ser o maior problema ao utilizar esse meio que está querendo.

Volto a reafirmar, o PHP não é nem de longe uma linguagem ideal pra se implementar stream, websocket ou qualquer coisa do gênero. Dá para implementar? Claro, mas o resultado não será muito satisfatório quando colocar em ambiente de produção.

Pelo que vi não existe um cabeçalho HTTP para limitar o tamanho de um range, então teria que recorrer a implementações em JavaScript ou Flash para isso. Caso contrário não terá muito controle, o que pode ser um problema imenso, pois enquanto o vídeo estiver carregando, o script do PHP estará sendo executado.

O que pode fazer é tentar separar em várias requisições solicitando partes diferentes do arquivo.

Utilizar essa maneira de entrega do arquivo por partes pode ser uma solução interessante, porem precisa tomar cuidado com a quantidade de memória que o seu script irá utilizar ou a quantidade threads usadas.

Para exemplificar, você fez seu sistema e ele entrega uma porcentagem do arquivo a cada requisição, vamos supor, de 10 em 10%.

Se você tiver um arquivo de tamanho médio, a entrega pode não gerar nenhum problema, o tempo de download será bom, e não haverá muitos requests consecutivos para o servidor.

Se você tiver um arquivo pequeno, a entrega pode começar a gerar problemas com um número maior de usuário utilizando, pois como as partes entregues do arquivo é muito pequena, a resposta será muito rápida e a necessidade de uma nova parte do arquivo surgirá tão rápido quanto. Sendo assim, o número de requisições consecutivas pode aumentar demais, e se tiver vários usuários solicitando o mesmo arquivo, serão várias threads criadas e como consequência um uso de processamento muito auto.

Se você tiver um arquivo muito grande, o PHP irá demorar a executar toda a entrega da requisição, e o PHP não foi feito para processar scripts durante muito tempo, [o PHP precisa morrer uma hora](https://software-gunslinger.tumblr.com/post/47131406821/php-is-meant-to-die).

### Controlando o tamanho dos ranges

Eu não encontrei nada sobre como controlar o buffer do player em HTML5, mas com certeza é possível, já que o YouTube faz isso, porem não acredito muito que ele trabalhe utilizando o PHP como serviço de stream, mas um sistema específico para isso.

Entretanto se quiser arriscar, algumas possíveis soluções:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Fundamentals/Audio_and_video_delivery/buffering_seeking_time_ranges
- https://www.sitepoint.com/essential-audio-and-video-events-for-html5/
- https://www.html5rocks.com/pt/tutorials/video/basics/
- https://developer.tizen.org/development/tutorials/web-application/w3chtml5supplementary-features/media/html5-video-and-audio-element
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071872/html5-video-force-abort-of-buffering
  -

Mas resolvendo esse problema com o limite do tamanho dos ranges, com testes e mais testes você poderá chegar a uma melhor solução do tamanho máximo ideal.

Para definir um tamanho de range eu sugiro utilizar um tamanho máximo fixo ou uma tabela range.

#### Tamanho máximo fixo

Definir um tamanho máximo para o range entregue é como dizer que a cada requisição entregará por exemplo 100Kb. então todas as requisições entregaram no máximo 100 Kb. Mas por que "no máximo"? Quando chegar no final do arquivo e faltar menos de 100 kb para entregar, então o valor do range tem que ser menor, por isso no máximo.

No caso da entrega de vídeo, o bom uso do range pode ser uma sacada interessante por lhe permite definir coisas do tipo, o vídeo sempre estará  carregado X segundos a frente.

A vantagem é que vai ser um valor sempre constante e talvez diminua a complexidade do código.

A desvantagem é que se um arquivo for menor do que o range definido será carregado completamente, e se for maior, talvez a quantidade terá requisições demais.

#### Tabela range

Utilizar uma tabela de ranges de bytes de entrega pode ser interessante pois você irá definir ranges de acordo com o tamanho do arquivo que está sendo entregue. Isto é, para um arquivo pequeno é um range, para o médio é outro e para um gigante um terceiro range.

Por exemplo:

```
Arquivo                    | Tamanho        | range máximo
pequeno 01                 | 10 bytes       | 100 kb
pequeno 02                 | 50 kb          | 100 kb
pequeno 03                 | 200kb          | 100 kb
médio 04                   | 1 Mb           | 200 kb
gigante                    | 1 Gb           | 1 Mb
```

## Referências

- https://blog.weckx.net/streaming-video-php/
- https://github.com/tuxxin/MP4Streaming
- https://ffmpeg.org/
- http://imasters.com.br/front-end/web-standards/pre-carregamento-de-video-em-html5/?trace=1519021197&source=single
- https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Video
- https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-p5-range-21.html
- http://www.media-division.com/the-right-way-to-handle-file-downloads-in-php/

Comment: Realmente fiquei interessado nessa ideia de limitar os ranges, problema é que não tenho a minima ideia de como o fazer, atualmente rodando os vídeos por php tenho a impressão de que eles começam a carregar mais rápido do que acessando o arquivo diretamente