# Streaming PHP e HTML

Tags: php

Eu tenho um vídeo em MP4.

O que eu preciso é transmitir esse vídeo via PHP (usando por exemplo um player HTML).

Só que essa transmisão, precisa parecer ser ao vivo (o usuário não pode avançar).

Existe alguma forma de carregar esse MP4 via PHP e fazer o php ir liberando aos poucos o arquivo?

Comment: Você pode tentar esconder os controles HTML de avançar.

Comment: Só que "Um dos principais problemas do PHP quando utilizado para stream, websocket ou qualquer coisa do gênero é que ele é péssimo para gerenciar memória, o PHP precisa morrer uma hora. Não é nada saudavel para o servidor deixar um script do PHP rodando por séculos. Este deve ser o maior problema ao utilizar esse meio que está querendo."  https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/170599/vantagens-e-desvantagens-de-usar-php-v%C3%ADdeo-stream?rq=1