# Gerenciar video com PHP

Tags: php, vídeo, buffer

Estou montando um sistema de gerenciamento de arquivo, mas estou tendo problemas com a exibição dos vídeos.

Ele possui um interpretador e em determinada parte tenho um "ignorador".

```
$mime = mime_content_type($path);

if(in_array($mime, self::$ignore)){
    $len = filesize($path);

    header("Content-type: $mime");
    header("Content-Length: {$len}");
    readfile($path);
    exit();
}
```

O problema é com os vídeos, que devido a serem dinâmicos não reproduzem corretamente.

#### Problema

- Ao renderizar o video deste modo, eu não consigo avançar no tempo a menos que o buffer já tenha sido carregado.
- Se o video termina eu não consigo voltar para assistir novamente.

#### Pesquisa

- [Support HTTP Header Range](https://gist.github.com/h2ero/ccf90f3592b06d9510655902b274b61d) - Não funcionou, pois o *range* não ocorre
- [Vantagens e desvantagens de usar PHP Vídeo Stream?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/170599)

#### Duvida

- Como gerenciar vídeos pelo PHP?

#### Nota

Estamos usando equipamentos com configurações diferentes, alguns rodam em Nginx e outros com Apache.

De tal forma que para deixar o mais compatível possível com ambos, todas as requisições são centralizadas e tratadas via PHP.

#### `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

#### Nginx

```
location / {
    try_files ~ ~ /index.php?url=$uri&$args;
}
```

Assim não é possível, criar regras de `.htaccess` ou *ngnix* como :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(webm|mp4)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L]
```

Comment: Guilherme achei estranho isto https://gist.github.com/h2ero/ccf90f3592b06d9510655902b274b61d não funcionar, mas olhei melhor o código, esse script provavelmente requer um ajuste no .htaccess, devido ao `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` que é somente gerado por reescrita, fora que com a experiencia que tenha a linha 4 não vai funcionar (`SCRIPT_FILENAME`). Fora que o autor colocou um `set_time_limit(0);` no meio do whille, o que acho que é redundancia. Vou refatorar esse código e te mando se os testes forem bem, você usa Nginx?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento pois é na verdade vou ter que ajustar a pergunta por esse motivo, você me lembrou, eu uso os dois. Nos temos alguns equipamentos que roram Nginx e em outros apache. mas vou editar explicando.

Comment: Mas se você for passar o enderenço/nome do video por "ID" do banco ou GET não precisará de ajustes, na verdade removeria bastante coisa ali :), acho que não precisa citar na pergunta, a não ser que seja uma exigência "criar rotas".

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Adicionei. Na verdade nesse sistema o ideal seria não criar rotas.

Answer (score 1):

Fazendo uma breve observação no script https://gist.github.com/h2ero/ccf90f3592b06d9510655902b274b61d haviam algumas "problemas", esse script provavelmente estava ajustado para um `.htaccess` **especifico**, ou seja ele teria que ser ajustado as duas necessidade, o mesmo vale para o Ngnix.

Presumo isto devido ao `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` que é somente gerado por reescrita, fora que com a experiencia que tenha a linha 4 não vai funcionar (`SCRIPT_FILENAME`). Fora que o autor colocou um `set_time_limit(0);` no meio do whille, o que acho que é redundancia. Não posso afirmar que isto comprometa o funcionamento e nem estou querendo criticar ninguém, só estou afirmando que o script esta feito para funcionar em uma situação especifica, eu refiz o script para que funcionasse com um GET (querystring) simples:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0); //Remove o limite

//Pega o mimetype
function mimeType($file)
{
    $mimetype = false;

    if (class_exists('finfo')) {//PHP5.4+
        $finfo     = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
        $mimetype  = finfo_file($finfo, $file);
        finfo_close($finfo);
    } else if (function_exists('mime_content_type')) {//php5.3 ou inferiror
        $mimetype = mime_content_type($file);
    }

    return $mimetype;
}

if (empty($_GET['video'])) {
    die('Video não definido');
}

//Pega a URL do video
$file = 'videos/' . str_replace('../', '', $_GET['video']);

$mime = mimeType($file);

if (!$mime || strpos($mime, 'video/') !== 0) {
    die('Erro ao ler o video ou mime-type inválido');
}

$fp = fopen($file, 'rb');

$size   = filesize($file); // File size
$length = $size;           // Content length
$start  = 0;               // Start byte
$end    = $size - 1;       // End byte

header('Content-type: ' . $mime);
header('Accept-Ranges: 0-' . $length);

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {
    $c_start = $start;
    $c_end   = $end;

    list(, $range) = explode('=', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], 2);
    if (strpos($range, ',') !== false) {
        header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
        header('Content-Range: bytes ' . $start . '-' . $end . '/' . $size);
        exit;
    }

    if ($range == '-') {
        $c_start = $size - substr($range, 1);
    } else {
        $range  = explode('-', $range);
        $c_start = $range[0];
        $c_end   = (isset($range[1]) && is_numeric($range[1])) ? $range[1] : $size;
    }

    $c_end = ($c_end > $end) ? $end : $c_end;

    if ($c_start > $c_end || $c_start > $size - 1 || $c_end >= $size) {
        header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
        header('Content-Range: bytes ' . $start . '-' . $end . '/' . $size);
        exit;
    }

    $start  = $c_start;
    $end    = $c_end;
    $length = $end - $start + 1;
    fseek($fp, $start);
    header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
}

header('Content-Range: bytes ' . $start . '-' . $end . '/' . $size);
header('Content-Length: ' . $length);

$buffer = 1024 * 8;
while (!feof($fp) && ($p = ftell($fp)) <= $end) {

    if ($p + $buffer > $end) {
        $buffer = $end - $p + 1;
    }

    echo fread($fp, $buffer);
    flush();
}

fclose($fp);
```

Se o endereço do vídeo for baseado em um ID do banco bastaria ajustar:

```
//Exemplo teórico, pode adaptar pro seu ORM ou mysqli, é apenas para esclarecer a lógica
$consulta = $pdo->prepare('SELECT filename FROM videos WHERE id = :id');

//Pega o ID pela QUERYSTRING
$consulta->bindValue(':id', $_GET['videoid'], PDO::PARAM_INT);

$consulta->execute();
$linha = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

//Pega a URL do video
$file = 'videos/' . $linha['filename'];
```

> **Atenção:** Estou olhando as docs e algumas coisas sobre HTTP para entender melhor o range, irei corrigir possiveis falhas no script em breve

---

### Testes

No chrome (opera) limitei para *3G Fast* (simulação), o HTML ficou assim:

```
<video src="range.php?video=1.mp4" controls preload="none"></video><hr>
<video src="range.php?video=2.mp4" controls preload="none"></video><hr>
<video src="range.php?video=3.mp4" controls preload="none"></video><hr>
```

E no console:

[image: console]

Dei o play no primeiro video e em seguida arrastei o controle para frente e resultou em:

[image: range]

Eu só não tenho certeza do porque gerou múltiplas requisições, mas creio que possa ser que o script ainda não é perfeito ou o download do vídeo após o "seek" dependa dos CODECs da máquina e/ou navegador (e talvez da velocidade da internet).

Imagem do "seekbar":

[image: seekbar]

Comment: Pelo que eu pesquisei isto esta correto, é devido ao protocolo 206.
Eu achei isso tambem [How to use PHP to output an mp4 video ?](http://www.phpmind.com/blog/2016/10/how-to-use-php-to-output-an-mp4-video/)

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert eu só acho (não tenho certeza) que o calculo do `Content-Range: bytes ....` possa estar errado em algum ponto, estou lendo e tentando ajustar, assim que possivel lhe envio os testes ou script ajustado :) ... PS: os teus videos são passados pela URL, rotas ou ID na queystring? Apesar que creio que pra ti isso não é nenhum mistério

Comment: Meus vídeos são passados via url, seria direto `http://domain/video.mp4`, neste momento não estou me preocupando com o player (<video>), de tal modo que estou simulando abrir a url do *source*.

Comment: So lembro que em tese se você quiser simular minha situação tudo acaba virando *queystring* em `^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1`

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert entendi, só mais uma duvida, seu videos devem ficar em uma pasta (rota) especifica? Tipo `http://site/video/1.webm` ou seria qualquer video em qualquer rota?

Comment: Todos eles também estão em um pasta, `APP_ROOT/Filmes/*.mp4`, mas o usuário nem sabe disso pois mesmo que ele digite `http://site/video1` eu posso mandar ele para `APP_ROOT/Filmes/filme7.mp4'.`

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert blz, vou criar um exemplo para htaccess e para o ngnix e te mando ;) (pode demorar um pouco, vou fazer uns testes pra ter certeza, apache2.4 e ngnix 1.6.3)

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65974/discussion-between-guilherme-lautert-and-guilherme-nascimento).